# Adding to my list array from my JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

This is what I am currently doing. I tried just pushing the values from my `json` into the links array, but upon entering the array the values become `undefined`. What is a better way to move the data and have it still be usable??

```
var links = [];
$.ajax({
  url: 'data.json',
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'get',
  cache: false,
  success: function(data) {
    $(data.emails).each(function(index, value) {
      links.push(value);
    });
  }
});

//data.json contains:
{
  "emails": [{
    "source": "1.11913372.-2@multexinvestornetwork.com",
    "target": "pallen@enron.com"
  }]
}
```

> result from using this code is the same. The values enter the array, but when you access them via links.(name of value) it returns 'undefined'

```
 $.each(data.emails, function(index, value) { 
        links.push(value);
        console.log(links);
        return value;
    });
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEQU6.png)

Comment: what is inside "data" ?

Comment: The real question is where are you returning to, and where do you check the `links` array, and why would that array have a `target` property ?

Comment: Where are you checking the `links` array? Be aware that the AJAX request is async.

Comment: i updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>        
<script type="text/javascript">
//alert("data");
var links = [];
   $.ajax({
         url: 'test1.php',
         type: 'post',
         dataType: 'json',
         data: {

         }
       }).done(function(data) {
        $.each(data.emails, function(index, value) { 
        links.push(value);
        console.log(links);
        return value;
        });
    });

    function getVal(){
        console.log(links[0].target);
    }
</script>
<button onclick="getVal()">Get target</button>
```

Comment: The main problem was that the call is asynchronous and I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

I think your success callback code is wrong,

the correct way to loop `data.emails` is,

```
   success: function(data) {
        $.each(data.emails, function(index, value) {  // <--- change this
            links.push(value);
            console.log(links);  //<--- updated 
            return value;
        });
    }
```

Comment: you are correct-ish, in that it is more correct to use $.each in this case, but, it isn't what is causing the problem. $() can create a collection from any array-like structure, and .each will iterate over it.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `console.log` on a key that doesn't exist. Modify your code to call and print out the array, not a random property.

```
var links = [];
    $.ajax({
    url: 'data.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        $(data.emails).each(function(index, value) {
            links.push(value);
            console.log(links);
            return value;
        });
    }
});
```